# iOS 8 Table View Controller performance issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

After updating to iOS 8, my app has severe performance issues when scrolling in a UITableView - it didn't at all on iOS 7. It seems to lag or constantly jump a little.

It affects both older (2nd gen.) and newer (4th gen. Retina) iPads, but not iPhones, as my iPhone 5 scrolls fine through TableViews constructed in the exact same manner.

**Important**: It seems to only affect UITableViewControllers presented *modally* in a *form sheet* - not table views created manually somewhere else in a default UIViewController. Not even a modally presented form sheet of UIViewController with a custom Table View (as a property, for instance) is affected.

Instruments says around 3% of CPU time goes to cellForRowAtIndex method, with that one being the most consuming method. Of that 3%, 75% goes to the line:

```
EventTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

cellForRowAtIndex looks like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tablecell";

    EventTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *thismsg = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    switch ([[thismsg objectForKey:@"type"] intValue]) {
        case 1:
        cell.eventTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;
        case 2:
      cell.eventTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        case 3:
       cell.eventTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:128.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1];
            break;
        case 4:
           cell.eventTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            break;
        default:
           cell.eventTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            break;

    }
    cell.eventTitleLabel.text = [thismsg objectForKey:@"m"];
    cell.timestampLabel.text = [thismsg objectForKey:@"t"];
    cell.authorNameLabel.text = [thismsg objectForKey:@"a"];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // this needs to be here, but removing it makes no difference to performance.
    return cell;
}
```

My subclassed cell has only a few labels made with IB, which are the ones the text is assigned to.

The Storyboard setup for the View Controller and the Table View Looks like this:
[image]

EventTableViewCell.h:

Properties linked to Storyboard's elements shown in above picture

```
@interface EventTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *eventTitleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timestampLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *authorNameLabel;

@end
```

EventTableViewCell.m:

```
@implementation EventTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // commenting out this method does nothing to performance, only makes it the wrong color
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


@end
```

Quick look at Debug Navigator during extreme scrolling up and down (nothing you would ever do as a normal user). Normal fast scrolling gives around 15% CPU usage. These peaks are at the 25% mark - i assume because they run on the same thread and the iPad has 4 available. The performance from scrolling quickly is identical to scrolling slowly, so the CPU doesn't seem to be involved in whether or not it is lagging. The 0% is after i stop scrolling to take the screenshot, indicating that the app is **not** busy doing anything else in the background or from other view controllers. And as you can see it doesn't leak memory either, as it keeps going down to around 23MB no matter how long I keep scrolling up and down.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried profiling the app?

Comment: could you please paste the code of your table view

Comment: @nickdnk If you want to become a serious iOS developer learn to use Instruments. I had to optimize a lot table view code in the past years. There are so many mistakes one can make. And Instruments helps with this and a lot more.

Comment: I'll get back to you with code examples later.
I realize there are mistakes one can make, but how these mistakes would only result in problems for iOS 8 is what makes me wonder if this is just me or if Apple did something weird.

Comment: This is silly: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"`

Comment: It is not silly. Generally allocating a new string instead of referencing an object that might change can solve some weird problems. This is definitely not the cause of any issues in this matter.

Comment: @nickdnk - So you're telling me that you have mutable strings in your dictionary???  And if one shows us that sort of silly code, he's probably doing a dozen other even sillier things that he hasn't shown us yet.

Comment: It sounds most likely that you're doing some sort of activity in the foreground that should be in the background -- accessing the web, a delay-based timer, etc.

Comment: Nope. Also, if I did it would cause problems in iOS 7 also. I tried basically emptying out the entire cellforrow-method. Still lags like hell. But ONLY in Native Table View Controller (I have several independent classes of this, and they all behave the same.

Comment: And yes in this case it might be unnecessary with the strings. I removed them - but that has nothing to do with this. The problem is that it doesn't matter what I do in the method. Same problem. And I'm doing nothing else anywhere as far as I can tell. Instruments says CPU at 0 when not scrolling and like 15-20 when scrolling fast. The subclassed table view cell only has a couple of labels. I updated the post with some screenshots and more code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** This has been fixed in iOS 10. I have no idea what the reason was, but updating devices to iOS 10 gives the same results as on iOS7 - smooth scrolling as expected. **EDIT AGAIN**: This problem has returned at 10.1 or 10.2. Still no idea what's going on.

Okay. After hours and hours of picking apart my app, I found the cause.

It turns out the problem was caused by the presenting View Controller, not the Table View Controller itself.

Here's how I found out, and how the symptoms connect:

It only affected native Table View Controllers because these were all presented by the same problematic VC. All other table views were presented elsewhere OR IN the problematic VC, which for some reason is okay.

It had nothing to do with the cellForRow-method or the class used to present each cell.

The presenting view controller is a full-screen iPad view controller with a lot of buttons. These buttons each represent an object in a room that one can tap for properties. This has been working fine up until iOS 8, where this thread started. For reasons I don't know, the buttons' alpha value of 0.7 made any presented Table View controller behave incorrectly. I found out by picking out elements one by one for the presenting view controller.

I disabled the line that set alpha for my buttons, and everything worked as expected and as it did on iOS 7.

I tried Google alpha-related issues with iOS 8 but got nothing.

Anyway - problem solved, albeit with the restriction that my buttons can no longer be transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Immediate feedback:

Register a NIB and use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. You're giving the table view more information when you fetch your cell and therefore substantially increasing the chance of good caching. You can also discard your `if ( cell == nil )` clause.

This bit is probably the most costly part:

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

Every view is layer backed and every layer has a GPU footprint. So you're causing allocations on both the CPU and GPU side. The whole point of tableview's view reuse is that creating views is expensive.

To resolve, incorporate that into the NIB if you go the NIB route, or at least do it only once, probably within `EventTableViewCell -initWithStyle:`.

Conversely, if you wanted to stick with a pure code approach, the following should work:

```
// e.g. in viewDidLoad, assuming you have self.tableView; this tells the
// tableview that the class EventTableViewCell is the thing that is used to
// display any data with which you'd supply the reuse
// identifier CellIdentifier
[self.tableView registerClass:[EventTableViewCell class] 
         forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

... elsewhere ...
-(UITableViewCell *)
  tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    EventTableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
           dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
           forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // cell now definitely exists and is non-nil if EventTableViewCell
    // is currently returning non-nil objects for 
    // initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:; there's definitely no point calling
    // that again, at least

    NSDictionary *thismsg = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
... etc ...
```

Of course, these are just my immediate reactions. If you've not run Instruments you don't even know whether the bottleneck is inside your tableview datasource. Just off the top of my head, it's just as possible that `EventTableViewCell` could be doing something expensive, that somebody else could be adding extra gesture recognisers and doing their own big processing task, etc.

Comment: Commenting out that entire block makes no difference whatsoever. I don't understand the first part? You cannot remove the if nil part, because the whole idea is to check if the cell was already created statically. This is default for all table views and is the code that Xcode automatically generates when you create a new subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: @nickdnk you're talking about iOS 5 and below. Check the documentation. I quote: "Prior to dequeueing any cells, call this method or the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: method to tell the table view how to create new cells. If a cell of the specified type is not currently in a reuse queue, **the table view uses the provided information to create a new cell object automatically.**" (emphasis added) (oh, and you can register a class instead of a NIB if you like; NIBs are easier because you can include them directly in the Storyboard, should you have kept up to date there)

Comment: Okay. Can you post a complete example? I honestly don't know what a nib really is. I've only ever used storyboards and just subclassed my TableViews, cells etc. Edit: And what I meant was that commenting out the entire background UIView-addition doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Okay - thanks. I did run Instruments. It tells me nothing except that my cellForRowAtIndex uses around 3% of the CPU time when scrolling. Your suggestions don't solve the problem either, unfortunately. I upvoted for effort and general tips. I assume this is something Apple must fix, because it doesn't seem like I did anything wrong, which also explains why it works flawlessly in iOS7.

Comment: Did it tell you what's using the other 97%? Or is it claiming that only 3% is in use? It's easy to imagine how that could technically be true were Apple to have introduced a bug: were you to use the first 3% of processing every second you'd hit 3% total and you'd be late for more than 96% of all frames.

Comment: Main Thread gets around 100% (95-97) and cellForRowAtIndex get the 3-4 percent left. Seems like it's idling. It only shows 15-20% total cpu usage when scrolling fast through the tableview.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I'm still fighting this. See updated post.